# I want to fill the color on specific section of line chart using MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, graph, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am programming the Android application using MP Android Chart v 2.1.6.
I want to fill color on specific section chart, for example, I want to fill gray color if `y < 5`, and white color if `y >= 5`.

[image]

I used this method, but it fills whole chart.

[image]

Comment: I think [this link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors) will help you

Comment: I think you gonna need to split it into datasets and set coloring on each.. I did it like that.. the only thing is then you get multiple entries in the legend.. but you can edit the legend and put there only the data you need..